Do we ever truly explain anything?
Every time we have come up with an explanation for anything, we have asked the further question of what explains that. Sure, by doing this, we make an advance in knowledge, but how does this make an explanatory advance exactly? Explanatory advance implies that we are getting closer and closer to a complete explanation. But if there is always a further why to be asked, in what sense are we getting closer to a full explanation if that does not exist?
Secondly, when considering causal explanations (I’m not sure if other kinds of explanations don’t just reduce to the causal kind), the “explanation” is usually pre existing matter transforming into another form. Thus, all we ever see is pre existing stuff turn into more, different kinds of stuff. I believe this idea has motivated many philosophers to not even be sure of whether causality is a real thing. But if causality isn’t a real thing, in what way is causal explanatory advance real?

Scientific explanations are quite useful: laser, GPS, medicine. What does not satisfy you? The eternal question about the meaning of human existence?

When you build a house, you do not build a foundation that connects to the center of the Earth, nor is it wise to try.

If you being explained completely: no. And for many if not most practical purposes, we don't need to. When we find exceptions, we adjust our theories, and the new theories hold until something better, again, comes along.


Do we ever truly explain anything?

As always, the answer depends on what we think an explanation really consists in. See? Can we ever truly explain what explanations consist in?
What about looking at what people (really?) do when they explain something and take that as what explanations really consist in?
Explanations presumably can only consist in logical inferences from premises which we believe are true of the real world (whatever we think that is). The limitation of our explanations is nothing if not the limitation of human rationality itself. Given how logic works, to prove B, we have to find some A such that we can convince ourselves both that A is true and that A implies B. But then should we not then prove that A is true and that A implies B. This would ask for an infinite regress.
Thus, to explain something, we have to start from something else and something else we have data about. Is that real enough?
We have apparently to be content with what we happen to believe and proceed from there, hopefully logically.
Thus, we explain water, and its properties, from H₃O+ and OH− ionised molecules, and their properties and interactions, and then we explain H₃O+ and OH− molecules, and their properties, from hydrogen and oxygen atoms etc.
If you think molecules, atoms and quarks are not sufficiently real, then nothing outside your own mind ever will.
Science is not about fictitious entities. It is an investigation of the real world. Scientific theories may obviously be false or approximative, but they can be as true as any assertion will ever be. In other words, if science for some reason cannot really be true, then no assertion about the real world will ever be either.

Scientific explanations do not purport to reveal what is "real." They have merely been shown to be sufficiently accurate models to explain and predict observations. Scientific explanations are premised on a particular causal model but are always subject to revision or refinement.
E.g. the path of a pitched baseball is sufficiently explained by Newtonian gravity plus aerodynamic forces. There is no need to look further to elementary particles, relativity, or quantum mechanics. That example shows that even admittedly truncated models can be useful.
